# Paypal does not sent item_number & item_name

Tags: paypal

Paypal does not sent item_number & item_name in some case,I don't know in which case. Basically Paypal sent item_number & item_name in all cases but in 1 entry I found its not send me any idea why this was happen?

Because I have tried same code many times and its working good for me.

Comment: That one transaction could have been by some different method that wasn't including the item name and number.  For example, it's possible somebody simply sent you a payment through the Send Money tab.

Comment: No, I have confirmed its done by my website. Because I am executing insert data log of paypal response in my database.

In that data log, I did not found item_number & item_name but its came with SUCCESS status.